# Adding kwargs to pandas apply statement with dictionary argument

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-cleaning

I have the following DataFrame from which I'm trying to obtain multiple aggregations via a dictionary argument into groupby().agg()

```
>>> apply_dict
{'Amount': ['sum', 'std'], 'TransactionDate': ['min']}
>>> df
  Account  Amount TransactionDate
0       A      10      10-20-2018
1       A      20      10-21-2018
>>> df.groupby('Account').agg(apply_dict)
        Amount           TransactionDate
           sum       std             min
Account                                 
A           30  7.071068      10-20-2018
```

However, the standard deviation is reported as sample stdev, but I would like to obtain the population stdev. **Is it possible to supply a kwarg to agg() when using a dictionary?** Trying the below call returns the same DataFrame as above:

```
>>> df.groupby('Account').agg(apply_dict, ddof=0)
        Amount           TransactionDate
           sum       std             min
Account                                 
A           30  7.071068      10-20-2018
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, just specify through a lambda

```
apply_dict = {'Amount': ['sum', ('std', lambda s: s.std(ddof=0))], 
              'TransactionDate': ['min']}
```

```
        Amount     TransactionDate
           sum std             min
Account                           
A           30   5      10-20-2018
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Would you mind explaining why the tuple syntax is used rather than just the lambda function?

Comment: @BrendonMachado you could use a lambda straight away i.e. `['sum', lambda s: s.std(....)]` but then the column name would be the weird output from `repr` of anonymous functions. The tuple `(name, function)` works as though a namedtuple and yields a nicer result